# frontend login with redirect to target page and 404 in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i am fighting with the following problem in an installation with many restricted pages. Many of this pages are linked from outside, from other sites.

So i need the following possibilites:

1. when the user is not logged in and the target page exists he should be redirected to a login page and then again redirected to the target page.
2. when the user is not logged in but the target page does *not* exist (= 404) then the user should be redirected to the login page and then aftrer login redirected to a 404 page.

Number 1 I can achieve with redirecting every 404 in the install tool to my login page (/?id=1234). But this ends in an infinite loop when the target page does not exist. The user is again and again redirected to the login page ...

Any ideas how to manage this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TypoScript option [`config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#typolinklinkaccessrestrictedpages) to handle cases like these.

The login form on the the page the user is redirected to then needs to take care of redirecting after a successful login. For `felogin` this can be achieved with the *Defined by GET/POST Parameters* redirect mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know both options, but this is not my problem. 
"typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages" deals with typolink, but i have to deal with links from external websites which are set manually. The redirect with fe_login works perfectly when the target page exists, but results in a infinite loop when the target page does not exist.

Comment: @lisardo I have the same problem... Did you find a solution?